# How to disable check box in alert dialog

Tags: android

I need to create alert dialog with 3 check boxes....And when top check box is cliked, 2 another one should be clicked and Disabled....How to do that? I tried to do that with onMultiChoiseItems()...but a cannot disable items there....Have you any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically create the checkboxes in a layout and use this layout with the Alert Dialog. This is an example where I react on a button click. You can as well react on a checkbox event and then change another checkbox:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);


        layout.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)  );
        layout.addView(input);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
     ...                
            }

        };
        Button btn = new Button(this);

        btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

        btn.setText("...");
        layout.addView(btn);
        alert.setView(layout);
```

Comment: That is make sens...BUT...I need text to be to the left side of check box...So..if i want to make View Layout programmatically...That will be like Text View + Chek Box in Linear Layout....Can i disable LinearLayout ?

Comment: It's looks like i should create List View with Adapter..etc..And to put it in Dialog....

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Enabling/disabling menu items on the fly](http://droidista.blogspot.com/2011/01/enablingdisabling-menu-items-on-fly.html).  It's a way to get items out of a dialog (created from XML) during creation and enable/disable them in code.